# IOS how to delete an object in core data swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

The entity is "User" which has 2 attributes(email and password). I want to delete a User with the attribute email = "dog@gmail.com". What do I do? I did this far, but I don't know how to delete with attribute. Which means I need to locate the User first then make the delete.

```
    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    context.deleteObject(User: NSManagedObject)
    context.save(nil)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to fetch user with desired name and password, then delete it by calling deleteObject method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a predicate to limit your fetch to only return the object you want, then you can delete it, here's an example:

```
    let appDel  = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var fetchError : NSError?

    let fetchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "email == %@", "dog@gmail.com")

    let fetchUsers                      = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
    fetchUsers.predicate                = fetchPredicate
    fetchUsers.returnsObjectsAsFaults   = false


    let fetchedUsers = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchUsers, error: &fetchError) as! [NSManagedObject]

    for fetchedUser in fetchedUsers {

        var deleteUserError: NSError?

        context.deleteObject(fetchedUser)
        context.save(&deleteUserError)
    }
```

Comment: This works and it's quite clear to understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
    if let fetchResults = try!managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [User] {
        for (var i=0; i<fetchResults.count; i++) {
            if fetchResults[i].email == "dog@gmail.com" {
                managedObjectContext.deleteObject(fetchResults[i])
                try!managedObjectContext.save()
            }
        }
     }
```